# Java, reading numbers from txt files with special symbols into two dimensional array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, filereader

So, to start with I'll try to explain what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm new to java and I'm willing to learn it. The problem :

Let's assume I have a txt file filled with something like this:

[image]

The pattern is : |   a   b   |, when a is an ID and b is the actual number. I've read about Scanner, FileReader and BufferedReader classes in java, I tried to use them to recover the integers from the file and save them to my two dimesnional array of integers([2][1000]). The [0][0-999] would be ID's and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpbyG.jpg)[0-999] would be actual numbers. Now heres the moment im stuck upon - I can read first two zeros, but then I don't know how to skip the | symbol.

My code for now :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ShortSearching {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] tall = new int[100];
        int i = 0, k = 0;
        Tab tablica = new Tab();
        File textFile = new File("byteObs.txt");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(textFile)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                k++;
                tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println(tall[i]);
                if (k == 2) {
                    scanner.findInLine("|");
                    scanner.skip("|");
                    k = 0;
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found: " + textFile.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }



        /*String byteObs = "byteObs.txt";
        File textFile = new File(byteObs);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(textFile);
        //short[] tabID,tabVal = new short[1000];
        byte k = 0;

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {


            for (int i = 0; i <= 999; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 999; j++) {
                    if (k != 2) {
                        if (input.hasNextShort()) {
                            //matrix[i][j] = input.nextShort();
                            //System.out.printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        input.skip("|");
                        k=0;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        input.close(); */
    }}
```

I tried it multiple ways, can't paste some of them, cause they are already deleted. I would be grateful if anyone would at least point me to the method I should read about to be able to skip this | symbol in my text file.

PS. I know the for loops numbers are wrong, I'll change them when I will fix the skipping symbol stuff.

EDIT
http://wklej.org/id/1543739/

Heres the full text.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and instead of image post actual text data stored in file so we could use it while creating solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanner in many of its methods expects pattern representing regular expressions (regex). This happens also in case of `skip` method, but in regex `|` is meta-character representing `OR` operator. To make it simple literal you need to escape it by adding `\` before it (remember that to create `\` literal in String you also need to escape it with another `\`).

So regex representing `|` character is `\|` which needs to be written as String `"\\|"`.

Other problem is that `skip` requires regex which needs to match entire part which needs to be skipped and this part must appear exactly after position of Scanner's cursor, so in case of data like

```
1 |
```

when we will invoke `nextInt()` cursor will be set right after `1` (I will mark it with `I`)

```
1I |
```

so pattern which we want to skip is `space`+`|`.

Last problem is that your file doesn't have correct values in all lines (it has lines containing only
`|     |` where we won't be able to use `nextInt()` because next element will not be int. In that case we can simply test if this line starts with integer by using `hasNextInt()` and if it doesn't read consume it without processing its content by invoking `nextLine()`.

So your code can look like

```
File textFile = new File("input.txt");
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(textFile)) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("id    = " + sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println("value = " + sc.nextInt());
            if (sc.hasNext("\\|"))
                sc.skip(" \\|");
        } else {
            sc.nextLine(); // skip line if it doens't contain more integers
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found: " + textFile);
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks :D 
Accepted the answer as soon as I saw this, sorry for the delay.